# Dart/Flutter: How to print something into the console from constructor

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor

I want to print something to the console from my constructor as shown in the snippet below, but I get the error

> ```
> Context: 'SeitenzahlenrechnerErgebnis.print' is defined here.
>   print(a);
> ```

How/where can I execute the print(a)?

```
class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  MyClass({this.test});
  int a = 77;
  // I would like to say
  // print(a);
  // here, but no way …

  @override
  _MyClassState createState() =>
      _MyClassState();
}
…
```

I am new to Flutter/Dart - would appreciate help a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to open a block body after the constructor and print it there.

```
void main() {
  Dog myDog = Dog();
}

class Dog {
  Dog() {
    print('woof');
  } 
}
```

Your case:

```
class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  MyClass({this.test}) {
    print(a);
  }
  int a = 77;

  @override
  _MyClassState createState() =>
      _MyClassState();
}
…
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how to use this in my example above.

Comment: @BNetz try it now

Comment: I see - this is the behavior I wanted, thanks a lot!